# multiple-target url using spring security 3.1

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, spring-security

i want multiple target url to be redirected to for the different roles of the users, how to achieve it using spring security 3.1, I have already done with the single target url, but i am not getting the help how to do it for the multiple url.

Comment: can you please elaborate what do you want to do ?

Comment: Also can we look at `spring config` that "you have already done" ?

Comment: I have more than one types of users in my application and one login page, so i need to redirect the user after login to the page according to their type....

Comment: <http pattern="/pages/login.jsf*" security="none"/>

    <http auto-config='true'>
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/pages/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
   login-page="/login"
   default-target-url="/pages/admin/manageSystemUser.jsf"
   authentication-failure-url="/login"/>
    </http>

Comment: See if the answer on this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326587/determine-target-url-based-on-roles-in-spring-security-3-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, Spring security 3 and above provides the handlers directly for this purpose
I used the SuccessAuthenticationHandler for my issue.:)