# determine target url based on roles in spring security 3.1

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-3

In spring security 3.0, we are having `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` class, in which we were using `determineTargetUrl()` method, which returned the url based on different roles.

Now, we are moving to spring security 3.1.0.RC3 and I am stuck how should I now determine the url based on different roles as `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` class has been removed from new version. Can anyone please give me steps in brief with some code so that I can implement custom filter to redirect to different pages for different roles.

Answer (score 22):

The best way to determine the target url based upon roles is to specify a target url in your Spring Security configuration as shown below. This will work in Spring 3.0 or 3.1

```
<http>
    ... 
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/default"/>
</http>
```

Then create a controller that processes the default-target-url. The controller should redirect or forward based upon rolls. Below is an example of using Spring MVC, but any type of controller will work (i.e. Struts, a Servlet, etc).

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController {
    @RequestMapping("/default")
    public String defaultAfterLogin(HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.isUserInRole("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            return "redirect:/users/sessions";
        }
        return "redirect:/messages/inbox";
    }
}
```

The advantages to this approach are it is not coupled to any specific implementation of Security, it is not coupled to any specific MVC implementation, and it works easily with Spring Security namespace configuration. A full example can be found in the [SecureMail](https://github.com/rwinch/spring-security-samples-securemail) project I presented at SpringOne this year.

An alternative is that you could create a custom [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-form-target). The implementation might extend SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler which is the default AuthenticationSuccessHandler. it could then be wired using the namespace as shown below.

```
<sec:http>
    <sec:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"/>
</sec:http>
<bean:bean class="example.MyCustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

I would not recommend doing this as it is tied to Spring Security API's and it is better to avoid that when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using Custom Authentication Success Handler to specify the redirection based on user role after successful authentication.

**You need to create Custom Authentication Success Handler as the following :**

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;

public class CustomeAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        handle(request, response, authentication);
    }

    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request,
                          HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException {
        String targetUrl = determineTargetUrl(authentication);
        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            return;
        }
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    protected String determineTargetUrl(Authentication authentication) {
        boolean isTeacher = false;
        boolean isAdmin = false;
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities
                = authentication.getAuthorities();

        for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
            if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_USER")) {
                isTeacher = true;
                break;
            } else if (grantedAuthority.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
                isAdmin = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isTeacher) {
            return "/user/account";
        } else if (isAdmin) {
            return "/admin/account";
        } else {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
    public void setRedirectStrategy(RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy) {
        this.redirectStrategy = redirectStrategy;
    }

    protected RedirectStrategy getRedirectStrategy() {
        return redirectStrategy;
    }
}
```

**Then modify spring security xml file and defined your bean and use it**

```
   <bean id="customeAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
          class="com.test.CustomeAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="false">
        <security:form-login login-page="/sign-in" login-processing-url="/sign-in" username-parameter="username"
                             password-parameter="password"
                             authentication-success-handler-ref="customeAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
                             always-use-default-target="true"
                             authentication-failure-url="/sign-in?error=true"/>

        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/>
     ..
     ..
    </security:http>
```