# Spring 3.0 Different Success pages for each role

Tags: spring, spring-security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [determine target url based on roles in spring security 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326587/determine-target-url-based-on-roles-in-spring-security-3-1)

Hello all I was wondering if anyone knew of any way to specify different Success pages for different roles using spring security 3.0. I have an ROLE_ADMIN and a ROLE_USER that should each be directed to different success pages upon login.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an answer for Spring Security 3.1 that also applies to Spring 3.0. See [determine target url based on roles in spring security 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326587/determine-target-url-based-on-roles-in-spring-security-3-1/8327582#8327582)

Comment: This was the way I originally had I just wasn't sure if it was the best way or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a single success page jsp, with security checks to determine what is shown.

E.g.

```
<security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">
<fmt:message key="welcomemessageadmin" />
</security:authorize>

<security:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_USER">
<fmt:message key="welcomemessageuser" />
</security:authorize>
```