# Unexpected redirect to login page after successful login

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-security, prettyfaces

I'm using Spring to handle security in my JSF application. I have a login page at `/login` and I've configured Spring like this:

```
<http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

I want the admin page at `/admin` to be available only for users with the `ROLE_ADMIN` role. Users with `ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_USER` may access pages starting from the application root.

When I login with a user having either role I see the page you should see after login. However, whatever my next action may be I get redirected to `/login` like I'm not logged in. Can someone please explain this as I'm trying to get this thing to work for a day now. I've been reading the Spring 3.1.x documentation but it doesn't give me a clue about how to solve the problem. I'm running Spring 3.1.1.Release by the way.

Extra bonus info: the page you should see after login has an element that should only render if the user had `ROLE_ADIN`. I can see that element after login. The problems began when I implemented PrettyFaces. I've searched the web for common problems and only came up with that the PrettyFaces filter should appear after the Spring security filter. This is the case so it should work right?

**UPDATE:** I've updated my config to use expressions. However the problem still exists.

```
<http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login" />
    <logout logout-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

Output in Firebug's console just after login (the page tries an AJAX call):

[image: Firebug console log]

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326587/determine-target-url-based-on-roles-in-spring-security-3-1) question may be related. But in the example you need Spring MVC, I believe that if you are using Spring Security you still have access to a request wrapped in a  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.

Comment: To clarify: you have two types of users: first type has **only** `ROLE_USER` and second has **only** `ROLE_ADMIN` (I mean XOR). Is this true?

Comment: @Xaerxess A user can have one role or both. The user I'm testing with only has `ROLE_ADMIN`.

Comment: @mael I don't think that's related. The redirect after login works as expected. Any call after that gets redirected to `/login`.

Comment: How do you handle "/" mapping? Isn't it mapped to login? Can you show the controller code?

Comment: @Xaerxess The "/" is handled by PrettyFaces. Spring checks the URL first. If the user isn't logged in it is redirected to "/login".

Comment: Hmm, that's a pity you didn't managed to run debug, because I can't say more without some logs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, always debug Spring Security when having problems (add `log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG`).

Second, I think that you wanted [`hasAnyRole`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/el-access.html):

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole(ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER)" />
```

plus add `use-expressions="true"` to `http`:

```
<http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" use-expressions="true">
```

to allow `ROLE_ADMIN` xor `ROLE_USER` users to access page. In your current config user must have both roles to access `/**`.

Comment: I've updated my config accordingly, see my updates answer. The problem still exists.

Comment: Can you turn Spring Security debug on and post logs in question, too?

Comment: I can't get the logging to work. I've tried this before and spent a couple of hours doing so. Now I've spent another couple of worthless hours trying. When I finally get it to work I'll post back, any chance you know a good guide that works for 3.1.1?

Comment: [Petclinic](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html) is for Spring Security 3.0, but I you don't know Spring Security at all it should be sufficient. If you want to catch up with 3.1, [read reference manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#new-3.1).

Comment: About logging: did you added `src/main/resources/log4j.properties` file like [in example](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/) + Spring Security line? BTW There's easier method in 3.1: just add `<debug />` in your `security-context.xml` - it's a bit less verbose, but we'll see.

Comment: Earlier today I've tried `<debug />`, this didn't supply useful information. I'm reading the documentation and using it's examples. I tried the Petclinic already (just now), didn't show any logging.

Comment: Just read through [this documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-logging), excluded commons-logging and configured log4j as described. Nothing.. not a line of info.

Comment: Don't exclude commons-logging unless you want to use slf4j. Normally, [simple log4j configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-logging-log4j) will be sufficient as it'll _work with the default JCL dependency (commons-logging)_. Doing **exactly** what's described in 1.3.2.3 should enable console debugging.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. The PrettyFaces filter had to be placed **before** the Spring security filter in web.xml. The Spring security filer doesn't get a chance to store the authentication token in the session. Logging didn't work because I'm running a JBoss server and JBoss is running log4j. To get it working I needed to exclude the log4j library using a JBoss deployment descriptor. Thanks for your support ;-)