# After successful LDAP authentication takes to login

Tags: active-directory, spring-security

I am new spring-security  I did spring authentication with ActiveDirectory, It was working after adding

```xml
<beans:bean id="myauthenticationrpovider" class="com.holcim.acl.rm.security.MyAuthoritySupplementingProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />
```

and bean code as follows

```java
public class MyAuthoritySupplementingProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private AuthenticationProvider delegate;

    public MyAuthoritySupplementingProvider(AuthenticationProvider delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        final Authentication a = delegate.authenticate(authentication);
        //get first username and full User Name from a i.e Authentication.

        Object auth = a.getPrincipal();
        String username;
        String userFullName;
        if(auth instanceof LdapUserDetailsImpl){

            LdapUserDetailsImpl userDetails = (LdapUserDetailsImpl) auth;
            String[] dn = userDetails.getDn().split(",");

            String[] temp = dn[0].split("=");
            userFullName = temp[1];

            username = ((LdapUserDetailsImpl) auth).getUsername();


            logger.debug("AD Authentication done ");
            logger.debug(userDetails.getDn());
            logger.debug("User Full Name " + temp[1]);
            logger.debug("UserName is :: "+ username);
        }

        // Load additional authorities and create an Authentication object
        //final List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = loadRolesFromDatabaseHere();
        List<AclAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<AclAuthority>();
        authorities.add(AclAuthority.ROLE_ADMIN);


        return new AbstractAuthenticationToken(authorities) {
            public Object getCredentials() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            public Object getPrincipal() {
                return a.getPrincipal();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return delegate.supports(authentication);
    }

}
```

application-security.xml as follows

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
    <!-- HTTP security configurations -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-processing-url="/static/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
    <logout logout-url="/static/j_spring_security_logout" />
       <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
      <intercept-url pattern="/choices/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll" />
      <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
 </http>
    <!-- Active directory authentication added by Kamlesh A. -->
    <!-- LDAP server details -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="myauthenticationrpovider" />
    </authentication-manager>  

    <beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider"  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:constructor-arg value="in.mycompany.net" />        
  <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:PPP" />
  <!--<beans:property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="grantedAuthoritiesMapper" />-->
  <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
  <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="myauthenticationrpovider" class="com.holcim.acl.rm.security.MyAuthoritySupplementingProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />
    </beans:bean> 
</beans:beans>
```

I have gone through so questions

[Spring Security redirect to previous page after successful login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573654/spring-security-redirect-to-previous-page-after-succesful-login)
as well as

[Unexpected redirect to login page after successful login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409308/unexpected-redirect-to-login-page-after-successful-login)

after successfull login it takes to

```
http://localhost:8080/static/j_spring_security_check
```

But if I try to open anyother url it again take to login

Comment: Why have you changed the default login filter URL to `/static/j_spring_security_check` ? Also note that your login page `/login` isn't included in the pattern `/login/**`so I'm surprised you can successfully log in at all. Can you post the debug log for the login form submission request?

Comment: @Luke Taylor. Initial appliction-security created by spring roo. Spring creates same structure. I haven't change anything in that  part and It was working :( I reverted to code to just confirm .. but it is working now.