# Redirect to url in controller based on role with jdbc authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, roles

I'm learning Spring Security. I've made a standard login and registration page based on a github skeleton project. As long as I only used one role in the DB I could easily manage the default success url by the one role what I got. But now I want to add two default url based on the ADMIN and USER role.
I've read this [determine target url based on roles in spring security 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326587/determine-target-url-based-on-roles-in-spring-security-3-1) answer here and I tried to implement it but the `isUserInRole()` method always return a false value. I'm using jdbc authentication.

My MVC config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"hu.kreszapp"})
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

}
```

My security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"hu.kreszapp"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String usersQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
    private String rolesQuery;


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.
                jdbcAuthentication()
                .usersByUsernameQuery(usersQuery)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(rolesQuery)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.
                sessionManagement() //session management
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS) //session management
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/home").hasRole("ADMIN")//hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/game").hasRole("USER").anyRequest()//hasAuthority("USER").anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/default")
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/templates/images/**");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");

        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");

    }
}
```

My controllers:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView home(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
        modelAndView.addObject("userName", "Welcome " + user.getUsername() +  " (" + user.getEmail() + ")");
        modelAndView.addObject("adminMessage","Content Available Only for Users with Admin Role");
        modelAndView.setViewName("/home");

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/game", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView game(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User user = userService.findUserByEmail(auth.getName());
        modelAndView.addObject("userName", "Welcome " + user.getUsername() +  " (" + user.getEmail() + ")");
        modelAndView.addObject("adminMessage","Content Available Only for Users with Admin Role");
        modelAndView.setViewName("/game");

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/default")
    public String default(HttpServletRequest request){
        Principal u = request.getUserPrincipal();
        logger.info("user principal:" + u.toString());

        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String role = auth.getAuthorities().toString();
        logger.info("Role:" + u.toString());


        boolean r1 = request.isUserInRole("USER");
        boolean r2 = request.isUserInRole("ADMIN");
        boolean r3 =request.isUserInRole("1");
        boolean r4 =request.isUserInRole("2");

        logger.info("isUserInRole values:"+ r1 + " " + r2 + " " + r3 +" "+ r4);



        if(request.isUserInRole("ADMIN")) {
            logger.info("Admin check lefut!");
            return "home";
        }
        logger.warn("Admin check nem fut let!");

        return "game";
    }
```

In my default controller - which is stands for to redirect to the specified page by role - the `request.isUserInRole("ADMIN")` method always returns with a false value... However I have user with ADMIN role in my DB and the logs also prove me that the specified user has the Admin role granted:

```
Principal u = request.getUserPrincipal();
    logger.info("user principal:" + u.toString());

    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String role = auth.getAuthorities().toString();
    logger.info("Role:" + u.toString());
```

My question is, why can't this method notify the ADMIN user and how could I manage to redirect by role with jdbc authentication?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The newest one I believe, spring security 4. I create the project with spring initializr about a month ago.

Comment: request.isUserInRole("USER") will be prefixed with ROLE_.  It'll look for ROLE_USER.  Are your roles in your database prefixed with ROLE_?

Comment: No, I don't have these prefixes... I'll try it at night. Add this as an answer and i will mark it if it's the solution. :) Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security prefixes roles with ROLE_.  The code `request.isUserInRole("USER")` will be looking for ROLE_USER.  If your roles in your database are not prefixed as well, they will not equal.

You can also set the prefix used by Spring Security in your `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .servletApi().rolePrefix("MY_ROLE_PREFIX_");
}
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html